# Angular2 router-outlet outputs component into ng-component

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angular2-template, angular2-directives, router-outlet

In Angular2 app I use Bootstrap's grid.
Module's main component's template provides a grid's row:

```
<div class="row">
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

And sub-components have Bootstrap's grid's columns:

```
<div class="col-md-8">Hello, world!</div>
<div class="col-md-4"></div>
```

The problem is Angular2 generates such a HTML:

```
<div class="row">
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    <ng-component>
        <div class="col-md-8">Hello, world!</div>
        <div class="col-md-4"></div>
    </ng-component>
</div>
```

So: it adds an **ng-component** tag, which breaks the structure, required by Bootstrap (the *column block* must be a child of a *row block*).

How can I prevent generation of the **ng-component** tag?

Comment: so how did you solved it?

Comment: How did you solve the problem?

Comment: Not solved yet: used different markup.

Comment: You wouldn't have this problem if it was using `ng-container` instead of `ng-component`. AFAIK `ng-component` is meant for internal use only but it's very easy to confuse them. But you didn't say what library you were actually using.

Comment: https://caniuse.com/css-display-contents is a theoretical solution

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because of `.row` class. It has an property of `display:flex` which is a container of flex items.

In this case `<ng-componet>` is now become a flex item and start having the default properties of flex items.

I will suggest you to change you HTML construction for now may be bootstrap team will fix this.

To get more info about default properties flex item you can click [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).

Comment: It's true the problem is due to the flex display. However, I can't change my construction because I'm using some UI libraries.

Answer (score 0):

This happen automatically, angular generates `ng-component` after a `router-outlet` and it has nothing to do with the use of css flex.

ng-component is the default tag name of the injected element, if another directive isn't given. as stated here https://stackoverflow.com/a/57702912/4320602

From https://medium.com/angular-in-depth/angular-router-series-secondary-outlets-primer-139206595e2

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<ng-component>Routed components go here</ng-component>
```

Technically, the router will place the routed components just after the router-outlet, within an  element. This happens automatically, so you don’t actually type the  element.

More info here:
https://www.bennadel.com/blog/3350-routable-view-components-don-t-need-selectors-in-angular-4-4-4---but-they-may-be-helpful.htm

Maybe a work around could be:

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

And sub-components have Bootstrap's grid's columns:

```
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8">Hello, world!</div>
    <div class="col-md-4"></div>
  </div
```

So angular generates this HTML:

```
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    <ng-component>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8">Hello, world!</div>
        <div class="col-md-4"></div>
      </div>
    </ng-component>
```

Answer (score 0):

Keep your `<div class="rows">` wrap in router-outlet

```
<router-outlet> <div class="rows">...</div> </router-outlet>
```

Considering the `<div class="rows">` is outsourced from another folder

Answer (score -3):

No it is not possible and it should not affect your styles.

Comment: Well, it does affect my styles :( If, via Chrome dev tools, I move contents of ng-component outside of ng-component - grid starts to behave as it should. ng-component definitely breaks the layout.

Comment: No. It does break my layout.