# What IS ng-component in Angular?

Tags: angular, ng-container

There are two very similar named directives (or attributes) in angular

**`ng-component`** and **[`ng-container`](https://angular.io/guide/structural-directives#ng-container-to-the-rescue)**

If you put `ng-component` instead of `ng-container` you'll get all kinds of weird behavior - such as automatic insertion of a `<router-outlet>`.

I've often wondered is there actually a purpose for `ng-component` in user code.

Is it a legacy thing? Is it internal only? Does it solve any problems?

Comment: +1 this if you only found out about `<ng-component>` because your IDE auto completed it for you when you intended to type `<ng-container>`.

Comment: Darn autocomplete!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Angular routers render the components they have navigated to using a [router outlet directive](https://angular.io/api/router/RouterOutlet). Unless a specific router outlet directive is specified, Angular will automatically place the routed component within an `<ng-component>` element (i.e., a default router outlet directive). You generally don't use this directive directly. You'd invoke it by using a `<router-outlet>` element. In other words, `ng-component` is the default tag name of the injected element, if another directive isn't given.

So yes, it is generally used internally. As stated [here](https://www.bennadel.com/blog/3350-routable-view-components-don-t-need-selectors-in-angular-4-4-4---but-they-may-be-helpful.htm):

> You could attach styles to the "ng-component" selector; however, given
>   the fact that a parent component may contain multiple router-outlet
>   elements (for named and unnamed views), providing a unique local
>   handle would make CSS selectors a bit more intuitive.

Answer (score 8):

Not sure if this would ever be beneficial (or is even intentional), but turns out if you don't specify a selector name then your component will be rendered within `ng-component` tags in the HTML.

```
@Component({ selector: '' })
```